# Large model conversion failed with "User-recoverable exit code from extractor: -532462766" error message

Tags: autodesk-forge

I was trying to convert a large NWD model (1.3GB) and it failed during the conversion with following error (JSON)

```js
{
  {
    "type": "manifest",
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "status": "failed",
    "progress": "complete",
    "region": "US",
    "urn": "dX**************ZGVsXzE5MDYwNy5ud2Q",
    "version": "1.0",
    "derivatives": [{
      "name": "Federated Model_190607.nwd",
      "hasThumbnail": "false",
      "status": "failed",
      "progress": "complete",
      "messages": [{
        "type": "error",
        "message": "User-recoverable exit code from extractor: -532462766",
        "code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
      }],
      "outputType": "svf",
      "children": [{
        "guid": "3e7750e3-4b52-4935-869b-acb9146ca834",
        "type": "geometry",
        "role": "3d",
        "name": "CPA-MDL-ARC-IRD-ICG-Basement Interior_IFCRWC.nwc",
        "status": "inprogress",
        "hasThumbnail": "false",
        "progress": "0% complete",
        "children": [{
          "guid": "73cdf6a4-11f4-4049-8fdb-85acfa17495b",
          "type": "view",
          "role": "3d",
          "name": "Default",
          "status": "inprogress"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
}
object {
  Autodesk.Forge.Model.DynamicJsonResponse
}
```

any ideas if this is due to large file or ?

Regards,

Afshin

Comment: Can you unmask the URN or send it over to forge.help@autodesk.com so we can investigate?

Comment: @BryanHuang thanks for the reply, just sent the email